Google SMTP not working on cPanel hosted Laravel project! Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587"
SMTP is working well in the localhost. But when I host the project in a cPanel, it gives me below error.
Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465": stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`server9.hostingbangladesh.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.gmail.com'

Current .env:
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=<MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS>
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

I checked the smtp configs. They are seems preety notmal.

Why does your server use a certificate for hostingbangladesh.com when connecting to Google's servers? Sounds like a proxy problem

@NicoHaase I did not specify any certificate. Only updated .env file.

You didn't, but anybody on your server did. Please ask the admins of the server why this is happening

Try with these changes:
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl


A code-only answer is not high quality. While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.
